# Input textbox background image to blinking

Tags: css, gwt

I wanted to make the background image in textbox to blink during errors.

Is there any way to make the background alone blink.

Thanks,
Bennet.

Comment: Code, fiddle, snapshot, etc?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a blinking background with css.

With jQuery you can do something like:

```
<input type="text" class="blinkClass" />
```

Script:
  var color1 = $('.blinkClass').css('background-color');
            var color2 = '#f00';

```
        function blinkBG() {

            $('.blinkClass').each(function () {

                if ($(this).css('background-color') == color1) {
                    $(this).css('background-color', color2)
                } else {
                    $(this).css('background-color', color1)
                }
            });
        }
     var t=   setInterval(blinkBG, 400)
```